# How to make self-signed certificate for localhost?

Tags: openssl, certificates

I did with a password and with the following fields
as root

```
openssl req -x509 -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout /etc/ssl/apache.key \
    -out /etc/ssl/apache.crt
```

Fields

```
Country: FI
State: Pirkanmaa
Locality: Tampere
Organization: masi
Organizational Unit Name: SSL Certificate Test
CommonName: 192.168.1.107/owncloud
EmailAddress: masi@gmail.com
```

Output: SSL handshake error in HTTPS. Expected output: HTTPS connection. 
HTTP works.

The CommonName should include the URL where you want to go, owncloud's thread [here](https://forum.owncloud.org/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=2418). 
I have tried unsuccessfully in commonname

- `192.168.1.107/owncloud`
- `192.168.1.107/`

Test OS for server: Debian 8.5.
Server: Raspberry Pi 3b. 
Owncloud-server: 8.2.5. 
Owncloud-client: 2.1.1. 
Systems-client: Debian 8.5.

Comment: If you are looking for generating new SSL certificate using SAN for localhost, steps on [this post](http://dltr.org/blog/server/597/Generate-new-SSL-certificate-using-SAN-for-localhost) worked for me on `Centos 7 / Vagrant / Chrome Browser`.

Comment: @DamodarBashyal Please, do not provide link only answer but some description too as an answer.

Answer (score 21):

> openssl req -x509 -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout /etc/ssl/apache.key -out /etc/ssl/apache.crt

You can't use this command to generate a well formed X.509 certificate. It will be malformed because the hostname is placed in the *Common Name (CN)*. Placing a hostname or IP Address in the CN is deprecated by both the IETF (most tools, like `wget` and `curl`) and CA/B Forums (CA's and Browsers).

According to both the IETF and CA/B Forums, Server names and IP Addresses always go in the *Subject Alternate Name (SAN)*. For the rules, see [RFC 5280, Internet X.509 Public Key Infrastructure Certificate and Certificate Revocation List (CRL) Profile](https://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5280.txt) and [CA/Browser Forum Baseline Requirements](https://cabforum.org/baseline-requirements-documents/).

You mostly need to use an OpenSSL configuration file and tailor it to suit your needs. Below is an example of one I use. It's called `example-com.conf`, and it's passed to the OpenSSL command via `-config example-com.conf`.

---

Also *note well*: all machines claim to be `localhost`, `localhost.localdomain`, etc. Be careful about issuing certificates for `localhost`. I'm *not* saying don't do it; just understand there are some risks involved.

Alternatives to `localhost` are:  (1) run DNS and issue certificates to the machine's DNS name. Or, (2) use static IP and include the static IP address.

---

The Browsers will still give you warnings about a self signed certificate that *does not* chain back to a trusted root. Tools like `curl` and `wget` will not complain, but you still need to trust you self signed with an option like cURL's `--cafile`. To overcome the Browser trust issue, you have to become your own CA.

*"Becoming your own CA"* is known as running a Private PKI. There's not much to it. You can do everything a Public CA can do. The only thing different is you will need to install *your* Root CA Certificate in the various stores. It's no different than, say, using cURL's `cacerts.pm`. `cacerts.pm` is just a collection of Root CA's, and now you have joined the club.

If you become your own CA, then be sure to burn your Root CA private key to disc and keep it offline. Then pop it in your CD/DVD drive when you need to sign a signing request. Now you are issuing certificates just like a Public CA.

None of this is terribly difficult once you sign one or two signing requests. I've been running a Private PKI for years at the house. All my devices and gadgets trust my CA.

For more information on becoming your own CA, see [How do you sign Certificate Signing Request with your Certification Authority](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21340898/608639) and [How to create a self-signed certificate with openssl?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10175812/608639).

---

From the comments in the configuration file below...

***Self Signed (note the addition of -x509)***

```
openssl req -config example-com.conf -new -x509 -sha256 -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout example-com.key.pem -days 365 -out example-com.cert.pem
```

***Signing Request (note the lack of -x509)***

```
openssl req -config example-com.conf -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout example-com.key.pem -days 365 -out example-com.req.pem
```

***Print a Self Signed***

```
openssl x509 -in example-com.cert.pem -text -noout
```

***Print a Signing Request***

```
openssl req -in example-com.req.pem -text -noout
```

***Configuration File***

```
# Self Signed (note the addition of -x509):
#     openssl req -config example-com.conf -new -x509 -sha256 -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout example-com.key.pem -days 365 -out example-com.cert.pem
# Signing Request (note the lack of -x509):
#     openssl req -config example-com.conf -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout example-com.key.pem -days 365 -out example-com.req.pem
# Print it:
#     openssl x509 -in example-com.cert.pem -text -noout
#     openssl req -in example-com.req.pem -text -noout

[ req ]
default_bits        = 2048
default_keyfile     = server-key.pem
distinguished_name  = subject
req_extensions      = req_ext
x509_extensions     = x509_ext
string_mask         = utf8only

# The Subject DN can be formed using X501 or RFC 4514 (see RFC 4519 for a description).
#   It's sort of a mashup. For example, RFC 4514 does not provide emailAddress.
[ subject ]
countryName         = Country Name (2 letter code)
countryName_default     = US

stateOrProvinceName     = State or Province Name (full name)
stateOrProvinceName_default = NY

localityName            = Locality Name (eg, city)
localityName_default        = New York

organizationName         = Organization Name (eg, company)
organizationName_default    = Example, LLC

# Use a friendly name here because it's presented to the user. The server's DNS
#   names are placed in Subject Alternate Names. Plus, DNS names here is deprecated
#   by both IETF and CA/Browser Forums. If you place a DNS name here, then you 
#   must include the DNS name in the SAN too (otherwise, Chrome and others that
#   strictly follow the CA/Browser Baseline Requirements will fail).
commonName          = Common Name (e.g. server FQDN or YOUR name)
commonName_default      = Example Company

emailAddress            = Email Address
emailAddress_default        = test@example.com

# Section x509_ext is used when generating a self-signed certificate. I.e., openssl req -x509 ...
[ x509_ext ]

subjectKeyIdentifier        = hash
authorityKeyIdentifier  = keyid,issuer

#  If RSA Key Transport bothers you, then remove keyEncipherment. TLS 1.3 is removing RSA
#  Key Transport in favor of exchanges with Forward Secrecy, like DHE and ECDHE.
basicConstraints        = CA:FALSE
keyUsage            = digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
subjectAltName          = @alternate_names
nsComment           = "OpenSSL Generated Certificate"

# RFC 5280, Section 4.2.1.12 makes EKU optional
# CA/Browser Baseline Requirements, Appendix (B)(3)(G) makes me confused
# extendedKeyUsage  = serverAuth, clientAuth

# Section req_ext is used when generating a certificate signing request. I.e., openssl req ...
[ req_ext ]

subjectKeyIdentifier        = hash

basicConstraints        = CA:FALSE
keyUsage            = digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
subjectAltName          = @alternate_names
nsComment           = "OpenSSL Generated Certificate"

# RFC 5280, Section 4.2.1.12 makes EKU optional
# CA/Browser Baseline Requirements, Appendix (B)(3)(G) makes me confused
# extendedKeyUsage  = serverAuth, clientAuth

[ alternate_names ]

DNS.1       = example.com
DNS.2       = www.example.com
DNS.3       = mail.example.com
DNS.4       = ftp.example.com

# Add these if you need them. But usually you don't want them or
#   need them in production. You may need them for development.
# DNS.5       = localhost
# DNS.6       = localhost.localdomain
# DNS.7       = 127.0.0.1

# IPv6 localhost
# DNS.8     = ::1
# DNS.9     = fe80::1
```

---

You may need to do the following for Chrome. Otherwise [Chrome may complain a *Common Name* is invalid (`ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID`)](https://superuser.com/a/1202506/173513). I'm not sure what the relationship is between an IP address in the SAN and a CN in this instance.

```
# IPv4 localhost
# IP.1       = 127.0.0.1

# IPv6 localhost
# IP.2     = ::1
```

Comment: Can you please add the default path to the config file? - - Can you please show complete work flow? About passing the file to openssl command etc. - - I did not manage to succeed with the previous answer so all needed pieces of informations are appreciated.

Comment: @Masi - *"Can you please add the default path to the config file?"* - Not sure what you mean. You can save it wherever you like. I run it from the desktop on many machines, and my home directory on others. I noticed you used `sudo`. Maybe your `.rnd` file is owned by `root`. If so, try a `sudo chown -R masi:masi /home/masi`. Then you will be able to read from it and write to it.

Comment: I am now using only Debian, not Ubuntu, so only root. Please, add your work flow as an example about keepinv file in Desktop and passing forward. I do not have a clear picture about the system.

Comment: Run one of the commands listed at the head of the file. The comments are there for copy/paste. Pick the one that suites your taste. If you are still trying to generate a self signed, then you run the command with `x509` in it (just like the comment says).

Comment: The author requested the deletion of this post "due to CA/B changes", but due to the number of votes and potential help it's provided over the years, I've restored it. Take the advice in the post as-given when it was given.

Comment: You saved me a lot of time. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The `CommonName` should be correspond with whatever is sent as the `Host:`
header in the HTTP request. In your case, that would be `192.168.1.107`
(without a trailing slash).

#### Configure hostname for a web server

Personally, I’d configure a friendly hostname for the web server.  In your
mail Apache configuration or virtual host configuration (likely to be at
`/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf` for Debian-based distributions),
use the `ServerName` or `ServerAlias` directive, e.g.,

```
ServerName owncloud.masi
```

Restart Apache and then and configure DNS or (more simply) add an entry in
each client’s `/etc/hosts` to point it to the correct IP address, e.g.,

```
192.168.1.107   owncloud.masi
```

Comment: My owncloud access is at `192.168.1.107`. The other thread says that you should include subdomain. I think it implies `192.168.1.107/owncloud`. However, I can be wrong.

Comment: Assume you use `ServerName owncloud.masi` in `.../sites-enabled/000-default.conf`. Is the *commonname* of SSL key then *owncloud.masi*?

Comment: Will the IP-address stop working? Similarly if you use `ServerAlias`?

Comment: Access via IP address should keep working for HTTP. BTW, we've reached the comment limits (so I've deleted my previous answers to your questions) and I'll have to go off-line soon.

Comment: *"The CommonName should be correspond with whatever is sent as the Host: header in the HTTP request"* - Wrong. Placing a hostname is the Common Name is deprecated by both the IETF and CA/B Forums. Server names and IP Addresses ***always*** go in the Subject Alternate Name per the IETF and CA/B Forums. Also see [How do you sign Certificate Signing Request with your Certification Authority](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21340898/608639) and [How to create a self-signed certificate with openssl?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10175812/608639)